# Haskell: List Comprehension to Combinatory

Tags: exception, haskell, list-comprehension

Inspired by this [article](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2009-March/057221.html). I was playing with translating functions from list comprehension to combinatory style. I found something interesting.

```
-- Example 1: List Comprehension 
*Main> [x|(x:_)<-["hi","hello",""]]
"hh"

-- Example 2: Combinatory
*Main> map head ["hi","hello",""]
"hh*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list

-- Example 3: List Comprehension (translated from Example 2)
*Main> [head xs|xs<-["hi","hello",""]]
"hh*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

It seems strange that example 1 does not throw an exception, because `(x:_)` pattern matches one of the definitions of `head`. Is there an implied `filter (not . null)` when using list comprehensions?

Comment: Very peculiar. Also note that the more "literal" monad translation fails: `["hi","hello",""] >>= (\(x:_) -> return x)` "Non-exhaustive patterns in lambda"

Comment: Note however that `do (x:_) <- ["hi","hello",""]; return x` yields `"hh"`.

Comment: Also note that `[ head s | s <- ["hi", "hello", ""]]` will also raise the `Prelude.head: empty list` exception.

Comment: By the way, if you feel the need to imitate this (occasionally useful) behavior outside of a list comprehension, [this package gives a similar effect](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/spoon), implemented via disreputable trickery. For example, `mapMaybe (spoon . head) ["hi", "hello", ""]` gives `"hh"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the [section on list comprehensions](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#list-comprehensions) in the Haskell report. So basically

```
[x|(x:_)<-["hi","hello",""]]
```

is translated as

```
let ok (x:_) = [ x ]
    ok _     = [ ]
in concatMap ok ["hi","hello",""]
```

P.S. Since list comprehensions can be translated into `do` expressions, a similar thing happens with `do` expressions, as detailed in the [section on do expressions](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#do-expressions). So the following will also produce the same result:

```
do (x:_)<-["hi","hello",""]
   return x
```

Comment: @David V. : via the Monad's `fail` method, which exists solely for this purpose (pattern match failure in do-notation).  See Daniel Wagner's comment to pigworker's answer.

Answer (score 7):

Pattern match failures are handled specially in list comprehensions. In case the pattern fails to match, the element is dropped. Hence you just get `"hh"` but nothing for the third list element, since the element doesn't match the pattern.

This is due to the definition of the `fail` function which is called by the list comprehension  in case a pattern fails to match some element:

```
fail _ = []
```

The correct parts of this answer are courtesy of `kmc` of `#haskell` fame. All the errors are mine, don't blame him.

Comment: How would you apply `fail` to `map head ["hi","hello",""]`?

Comment: @snmcdonald: You wouldn't map `head` over the list in the first place but rather a function which calls `fail` instead of being undefined for empty lists. For example, `concatMap (\s -> if s == [] then [] else [head s]) ["hi", "hello", ""]` which yields `"hh"`.

Comment: @snmcdonald See my comment on pigworker's answer below for clarification of how `fail` arises when translating list comprehensions.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. When you qualify a list comprehension by pattern matching, the values which don't match are filtered out, getting rid of the empty list in your Example 1. In Example 3, the empty list matches the pattern `xs` so is not filtered, then `head xs` fails. The point of pattern matching is the safe combination of constructor discrimination with component selection!

You can achieve the same dubious effect with an *irrefutable* pattern, lazily performing the selection without the discrimination.

```
Prelude> [x|(~(x:_))<-["hi","hello",""]]
"hh*** Exception: <interactive>:1:0-30: Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern (x : _)
```

List comprehensions neatly package uses of `map`, `concat`, and thus `filter`.

Comment: So literally it translates `[x|x<-(x:_)<-["hi","hello",""]` == `map head $ filter (not . null) ["hi","hello",""]`?

Comment: The literal translation of `[x | (x:_) <- ["hi", "hello", ""]]` is `["hi", "hello", ""] >>= \s -> case s of { x:_ -> [x]; _ -> fail "inexhaustive pattern match" }`.