# Non-exhaustive pattern in Haskell list comprehension

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't Haskell list comprehensions cause an error when pattern match fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649274/why-dont-haskell-list-comprehensions-cause-an-error-when-pattern-match-fails)

Today I saw the following code:

```
Prelude> [a | Just a <- [Just 10, Nothing, Just 20]]
[10, 20]
```

It works. But I thought that the above list comprehension is just syntactic sugar for...

```
[Just 10, Nothing, Just 20] >>= (\(Just x) -> return x)
```

...for which Haskell, when encountering the `Nothing`, would emit an error `*** Exception: Non-exhaustive patterns in lambda`.

So my question is: what does `[a | Just a <- [Just 10, Nothing, Just 20]]` translate into (in terms of monadic code) that makes it ignore the `Nothing`?

Comment: @ephemient: Thanks! The post you linked to answers my question. And I've found [another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007222/haskell-list-comprehension-to-combinatory). The reason I didn't find these posts before I posted my question is because they don't contain the word "exhaustive", which is Haskell's term for the problem.

(I'm new to StackOverflow and am not sure what I'm supposed to do. Should I delete this question? It'd still be useful for people who'd type "[non-]exhaustive".)

Comment: You don't need to delete -- eventually it will be closed as a duplicate, which means there will be a large link up top forwarding people from here to the next with the answer.  And, as you note, it's more useful to keep around than to kill :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the best answer in [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649274/why-dont-haskell-list-comprehensions-cause-an-error-when-pattern-match-fails) is actually the one referencing 'compiler magic'.  You're matching the pattern `Just x`, and according to the [Haskell 2010 Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11) the behaviour is specified as

> .. if a match fails then that element of the list is simply skipped over.

So I think implementations are free to do this as they please (i.e., the desugaring is not necessarily unique).